# How can I resolve error 'No best type found for implicitly-typed array' while creating unique constraint on properties of different types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-5.0

**QUESTION**: Using EF Core (v5), how can I resolve the compiler error 'No best type found for implicitly-typed array' in a way that allow me to create a unique database constraint on multiple properties of different types?

I'm using code such as this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasAlternateKey(entity => new [] {entity.COL1, entity.COL2}).HasName("UniqueCOL1_COL2");

// example sourced from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/187856/code-first-unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns.html#answer-190078
```

In my case, I'm seeing a compiler error `No best type found for implicitly-typed array`, because `COL1` and `COL2` are of different types (string and int in this case).

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535357/no-best-type-found-for-implicitly-typed-array/68230328#68230328) explains the cause of the error, but does not explain how I can resolve the issue highlighted by my question.

I tried using an array of objects but that didn't work:

```cs
new object[] {entity.COL1, entity.COL2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using an anonymous object. For example:

```cs
builder.HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.SomeInt, e.SomeString })
```